# Fetch only one child record of a parent in soql

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, query, controller

I have a requirement to fetch Timecard records that are related to a Project.

Below is my query:

```
List <Timecard__c> timecard = [
  SELECT ID,Project__c,resource_name__c  
  FROM Timecard__c 
  Where Project__c != null];
```

The issue here is that, for each project, there are multiple timecards logged by a resource.
Eg: Resource A has 100 Timecard records under a Project.

Now, is there anyway that i can fetch only one Timecard record related to a resource for a project? This timecard record can be any random record per resource.

Please suggest.

Comment: What do you want? The most recent? Any random one? Or maybe a sum of all of the timecards? How can we help here?

Comment: Well - you need to provide us with selection criteria. WHICH single record do you need? Oldest? Newest? Most recently updated…?

Comment: @sfdcfox, I just need one timecard record per resource under a project. It can be a random one..I have updated my question with the same info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: you cannot make aggregate function in subquery, so the 1st approach isn't for you.

You can use subquery from a Project__c record:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, resource_name__c FROM Timecard__r ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Project__c
```

UPDATE: you need GROUP BY CUBE ([link to documentation GROUP BY CUBE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_cube.htm))

If the solution above is not suitable for you, you can try to use AggregateResult and get latest Timecard__c for each Project__c and each resource_name__c. However, you can encounter problem with `System.QueryException: Aggregate query does not support queryMore(), use LIMIT to restrict the results to a single batch`, if you have a lot of Timecard__c records.

```
List<Id> ids = new List<Id>();
for (AggregateResult res : [SELECT Project__c, resource_name__c, MAX(Id) maxId FROM Timecard__c WHERE Project__c != NULL GROUP BY CUBE (Project__c, resource_name__c) ORDER BY GROUPING(Project__c), GROUPING(resource_name__c)]) {
    ids.add((Id) res.get('maxId'));
}

List <Timecard__c> timecard = [
        SELECT ID, Project__c, resource_name__c
        FROM Timecard__c
        WHERE Id IN :ids];
```

Comment: With this i logic could able to query one timecard record of project but is there anyway that i can one timecard record of resource under a project? Each timecard has a resource name and the query should return 1 timecard record per resource. Please suggest

Comment: Sorry, I have misunderstood you. Sure, I will update the answer @SFDCUser